# How to do conditional formatting on Chart axis values?

Tags: excel

I have a chart where I want to format values based on a cell selected type: "Percentage" or "Number".

If "Percentage" is selected I want to display chart values like "0.00%", else I want to display values: "# ##0"

I found only a way to have only one number format :

[image]

Also The section Conditionnal Formating is disabled when selecting the chart.

Is there a way to make this happend ?

Comment: Use a formula in your axis cells rather than trying a conditional format on the axis - `=IF($B$2="Percentage",TEXT($B$5:$B$9,"0.00%"),TEXT($B$5:$B$9,"#,##0"))`

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook thank you for your answer. I tried this solution.. But it seem that the numbers are no longer readable by the chart... Is there any other way I can go aroud it and make it work ?